Would wingsails be viable and/or competitive with traditional sails at a lower tech-level?
Wingsails are designed to take full advantage of lift for propulsion, with less drag when sailing into the wind. This makes them more efficient at all points of sail.
However, is that enough to make them competitive with traditional sails? For a preindustrial society, it would certainly be more difficulty (and therefore expensive) to make a sail capable of internally adjusting its camber, as a wingsail must be - and possibly outright impossible. (I saw this question, but it seems to be more about using alternative sail materials, and the answer and comments seem to deal entirely with conventional sails). There's also the problem that the sail area can't be adjusted beyond taking the entire wingsail down; a potentially crippling drawback in high winds.
Where would wingsails fall on the scale of practicality for a preindustrial society, from "impossible for mortals", to "disadvantages/cost relegate them to niche use", to "advantages and drawbacks make them broadly comparable to traditional sails", to "so advantageous they've largely replaced traditional sails"?

VTC: Needs more focus. (Or in plain language, only one question is allowed per question.) P.S. (1) Note that wingsails morph into windsails in the second paragraph. (2) "Points of attack" looks like a cross between points of sail and angles of attack. (3) It's not that (rigid) wingsails are more vulnerable to high winds, it's that their surface area is fixed and cannot be adapted to wind conditions. (This is a very bad thing, I am told.)

If I understand correctly, the main reason being unable to adapt the surface area is so bad is that in conditions of high wind you're screwed. Good shout on the typos (I swear I already corrected the windsail one; either it snuck back in somehow or I made that mistake in two places). I'll see about tightening up the question.

Wingsails have been built with the ability to reef, some with the ability to adjust camber as well (a shaped mast with conventional fabric sail, raised in a track in the trailing edge of the mast; camber is adjusted via trailing edge tension, reefing by lowering the sail (so you both reduce area and reduce the wind velocity on the active portion of the sail).

Similar to my comment on your next question (I'm working backward), what's stopping you from simply using wing sails to replace traditional sail? We don't deal with Real World engineering, but suspension of disbelief in an imaginary world of your own creation (see [help/on-topic]). From a practical standpoint, what you're asking is, "why wouldn't a race car be a good substitute for a box truck?" These sails have a different dynamic, and therefore a different purpose, but that needn't stop you with your worldbuilding. What's stopping you from using them?

@JBH Well, that's exactly what I'm trying to figure out. What is the 'dynamic' between the two? Is it like a car vs a truck, where both serve different purposes well enough that there's no reason to replace one with the other? Or is it more like a car vs a horse-drawn carriage, where one's advantages over the other so greatly outweigh the downsides that it basically replaces it?

@PoeticallyPsychotic Humanity still uses wingsails, so the carrige-vs-car comparision isn't relevant, but I'm wondering what you goal is. Stack Exchange is not meant to replace an education or research. It's purpose is to solve a specific and objective problem. What problem do you have that your research hasn't helped with? Keeping in mind, using a math textbook as an example, our goal is to help you answer a question after you've made an effort to answer it yourself - our goal isn't to provide you with the book.

Seafaring nations put a lot of effort into maximising efficiency of optimising ships for the desired purpose (be that trade, speed, or war). Their well-being depended on it. Without claiming expertise, I'd suggest that if it was possible with the technology and materials available to create wingsails that would outperform traditional sails, it would have happened.

@user111403 I typically share this sentiment, but by the time fixed winged design was being refined in the late 19th century, steam ships were swiftly making sails obsolete.
